# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: iis, mime-types, referenceerror

I know a lot of people have asked this question before but none of the answers given have helped me. I used `SVN` to update a project I have been working on with others and all of a sudden I started getting these errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain:  

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I checked out a clean version from `SVN` of the project, but I still get the same errors. The weird thing is that the project works doesn't work in any browser for me but it works fine on my colleagues' machines.

I have tried changing file permissions as well as the `ContentType` in `regedit` with no luck. I wouldn't think it's a problem with my code since it is identical to what my colleagues have and it works for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that for some reason my IIS manager didn't have and MIME type references so I just added that and it worked!